# Call a C# method from an html a tag

Tags: c#, html, hyperlink

I have the following C# method, how can I call it from an HTML a tag?

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onclick="MyFunction()">CLICK</a>
public void MyFunction()
{
    Response.Write("<script>alert('Hello');</script>");
}
```

Comment: wow. Why can't you just do this using plain javascript?

Comment: That's not possible in the way you are doing it, you only can call javascript methods in html.

Comment: But you can create javascript function, with an ajax call to a c# page that can execute MyFunction.

Comment: @Stan can you give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jQuery ajax to MVC action:

```
function CallMyCShartAtion(id)
{
   $.ajax({
      url: 'urlToController', //path to the contoller's action
      data: { id: id }
   }).done(function() {
      alert('Added'); 
   });
}
```

And then

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onclick="CallMyCShartAtion(5)">CLICK</a>
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1):

This isn't directly possible (at least not in the way you're trying to do it). First of all, JavaScript is typically a client-side language, which can be run in your browser, as opposed to C# (or Java or PHP or...) which is typically run on the server side.

In order to accomplish this task like you're asking for here you need to

- have some kind of backend in place (say, in C#)
- issue a request from the client side (frontend) to the backend (e.g. using [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/))

Answer (score 0):

Use direct javascript for that functionality, no need to use c#

```
<a href="#" runat="server" onclick="alert('hello')">CLICK</a>
```

Comment: And then how I should call the C# function?

Comment: @Ado it would help if you clarify why you *need* to call C# in the first place. Can you describe what you're trying to do? The example you give in the post is straightforward to do in JavaScript itself without ever calling C#.

Comment: Well, as my questions says, I am trying to call my C# method from a link.

Comment: @Ado Yes, but why? What are you trying to accomplish with the C# method and why do you need to call it? Why can't you do it in JavaScript directly?

Comment: @EJoshuaS This C# method is used from other code, and I don't want to repeat the same code.